# TopTabs React Navigation Navigation WIX [V2]

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I am using **react-native-navigation** and I want to implement a **topTabs** screen that holds two other tabs [tab1 and tab2], it doesn't seem to be a how in the docs, so I used this code replacing the existing one of the **bottomTabs**, the swipe between screens happens but there's no buttons nor icons as the bottom one.

```
  Navigation.setRoot({
        root: {
          sideMenu: {
            left: {
              component: {
                name: 'app.Drawer',
              },
            },
            center: {
              topTabs: {
                children: [
                  {
                    component: {
                      name: 'Tab1',
                      options: {
                        topTab: {
                          title: 'Tab 1',
                          icon: require('../assets/icons/tab1.png'),
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  },
                  {
                    component: {
                      name: 'Tab2',
                      options: {
                        topTab: {
                          title: 'Tab 2',
                          icon: require('../assets/icons/tab2.png'),
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  },
                ],
              },
            },
          },
        },
      });
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no top tabs in React Native Navigation v2. From what i can understand you might need lib like `react-native-tab-view`

Comment: @ketimaBu I am having the exact same issue, have you solved this yet ?